# Windows task scheduler does not kill child process

Tags: batch, process, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2012, task-scheduler

My task scheduler task has got one action: `Start application`--> `D:\test.bat`
The batch `test.bat` spawns a child process (for example):

```
notepad.exe
```

When I manually start this task and end this task, it does not stop notepad.exe. How can I achieve to kill all child processes like notepad.exe without accidantly closing other notepad.exe processes?

Edit:
The final goal is to have run notepad.exe from friday 07am - 15pm.
When I use powershell instead of batch, it works.

I am running Windows Server 2012 R2 (Version 6.3.9600)

Comment: No worries, I'm glad to hear you found a working solution using PowerShell.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT - Sure, but what about batch :)

Comment: Pete - I created this batch script here: https://justpaste.it/1iaec but it is not working as expected. I had something like this in mind and would've made it more hidden but the PID is not matching as expected for the child process I believe and I have to call it quits for today since work took it's toll on my brain. Maybe this will give you an idea or maybe you can figure it out. I think PowerShell may be a good solution and I know how to make a batch script run PowerShell commands transparently. Will check in tomorrow to see if you have any updates but I'll try more when my brain rests.